# SSL certificate for static site build with harpjs.com, host on surge.sh

Tags: ssl, web-hosting, static-site

I got a little site build with harpjs and host on surge.sh. They provide free basic ssl for their exemple.surge.sh domain but it cost 13$/month to be able to add ssl to custom domain.. I was wondering if anyone have a free solution for me. I've tried certbot, but nothing concluent.. Dunno what's wrong. (error)

```
An unexpected error occurred:
```

DialogError
Please see the logfiles in /var/log/letsencrypt for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Let me clear many things about SSL.

First, now are called TLS. SSL is deprecated.
Second, yes you can get free TLS.  You can even generate your own TLS, however it's not the best path.
Letsencypt is a TLS as a service, free of charge.
Third, AWS offers free TLS,  just get an ELB or a Cloudfront.

Here are some options:

I think this hosting service you use  is very expensive.  You can host a static or dynamic site on [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com) (using S3+CF or EC2+CF, respectively), with free TLS, free of charge for the first 12 months (free tier). After free tier period, the price is per usage. On AWS, setting up a TLS is very easy,  easier than letsencrypt, and easier and cheaper than you emitting yor own TLS.

Another option, keep your current host but put a CDN in front of it, AWS offers Cloudfront with frre TLS at reasonable cost (for CF service). Also [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/plans/) offers a very good CDN with TLS capabilities, IPv6 and a free plan.

If you go for [Let´s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org), be sure your hosting service allows you to upload the certificates.